# adding an entry to an entity's attribute

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, php-5.3

I have the following entity/class:

```
class Product
{

  /**
     * @Groups({"marketplace"}) 
     * @Accessor(getter="getShopRef")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\MainBundle\Entity\Shop", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE" , nullable=false)
     */
    protected $shop;

     /**
     * Set shop
     *
     * @param Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\Shop $shop
     * @return Product
     */
     public function setShop(\Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\Shop $shop)
     {
        $this->shop = $shop;

        return $this;
     }

    /*
    * reference of shop
    */
    public function getShopRef()
    {
        return array(
            "id"=>$this->shop->getId(),
            "name" => $this->shop->getName(),
            "description" => $this->shop->getDescription(),
            "shoplogo" =>  $this->shop->getShoplogo(),
            "ref"=>"/shop/".$this->shop->getId(),
            "is_locked" => $this->shop->getIsLocked(),
            "like_count" => $this->shop->getOwner()->getLikeCount(),
            "followers_count" => count($this->shop->getOwner()->getFollowers()),
            "following_count" => count($this->shop->getOwner()->getFollowing()),
        );
    }
}
```

Esentially what the above code is saying is to use this custom getter when I ask for the shop.

Say I have a `Product` object called `$product` and I wanted to add a new key to the shopref array/dictionary called "`recent_items`". How do I do so? So far I have been trying to do this:

```
$product->getShopRef()["recent_items"] = $userRecentItem;
```

but this does not work. Nothing is set on the shop ref. I expect that by doing that the 'recent_items' will be set on the shop_ref.

Comment: The error description *"but this does not work."* is merely a no-go here on the website. You need to be more specific: Why did you exepect it to work (show the  manual where this is written to work - at least where you thought so), what did you expect it to do/return, what does it do/return instead? Is there a specific PHP error, warning or notice? - I think you're using PHP 5.4 code incompatible with PHP 5.3 btw - etc. pp.

Comment: Well you should demonstrate how you check that (code) and also the values / errors (e.g. var_dump(), if it's not set, isn't there an undefined index warning probably etc. pp.) - And again: Why did you expect this to work actually? Can you explain?

Comment: I was thinking that when I do getShopRef() that would give me the reference and not the copy and so I think that will work. I am not getting any warning.

Comment: How can you say you get a copy?

Comment: @hakre since it is not working then I assume I am working with the copy and not the actual reference.

Comment: You are probably getting confused because your `getShopRef()` returns a new array, not an object you already have. You could add a property in `Product` containing this array and work from here but it will mainly depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @cheesemacfly I don't want to add a property from the Product class as I wanted to do this from outside the class

Comment: What I mean is that `$product->getShopRef()` returns an array. But if you don't store this array somewhere, you just "loose it". The fact that since PHP 5.4 you can dereference the result of a method call directly doesn't mean that the return object will be magically kept available. Every time you call the method, a new array is returned.